# Damage obtain during attack

Tags: fallout-shelter

How can I lessen the damage received by my dwellers during the mole rat or radroach attacks? Do I need to boost the Endurance Stat of every dweller I have?

Answer (score 4):

Only leveling up will increase your dweller's HP, which effectively reduces the percentage of damage you take.  The increase is based on your END score.  It is affected by outfit.

So if you want to maximize a dweller's HP, have a newborn train to 10 END, equip Heavy Wasteland Gear for +7 END, and send them to Explore until they hit level 50.